# Can not open a file from nas for writing by openoffice

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, samba, openoffice

I have a NAS drive and several files in it.

I can create files or delete files.

I have a file with extension *.xslx and when I check the permission, I can see:

```
ll
total 5
drwx------ 1 m m    0 Apr 11 19:50 ./
drwx------ 1 m m    0 Apr 11 19:50 ../
-rwx------ 1 m m 4779 Apr 11 21:29 test.xlsx*
```

when I want to open this file with OpenOffice 7.1.2.2, I am getting an error that the file is open with other users and can not be opened for writing.

I can edit the file if I move it to the desktop. and copy it back to NAS drive (so it is not locked as I can write on it).

what is the problem and how can I fix it?

it should be noted that the NAS uses SAMBA 1.0 and I enabled it in ubuntu 20.04.

## Edit 1

there is no lock file:

```
ls -lart
total 5
drwx------ 1 m m    0 Apr 11 19:50 ..
drwx------ 1 m m    0 Apr 11 19:50 .
-rwx------ 1 m m 4779 Apr 11 21:29 test.xlsx
```

Comment: Assuming that you are `m`, there probably is a lock-file somewhere. That would be `.~lock.` in the same directory. Try an `ls -lart` to see.

Comment: @LjmDullaart please see the edited question. there is no lock file.

Comment: My first guess would be the lock file is in /tmp. Also, why does a spreed sheet need execute permissions, i.e., -rwx------?  I would guess the permissions should be  -rw------- maybe it's still running? I would do a "ps -ef" and do a grep for name of the application.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I can not change permission as the samba server is not supporting it. I checked /tmp and also run ps and found that there is no lock file or the file is not running.

Comment: Try typing "lslocks" and see what pops out.